# Bootstrap checkbox with razor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor

I want to replace an old-style checkbox with a Bootstrap-style one, but saving the form does not save the checked value.

I have replaced

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { id = "Name" })
```

with

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="@Model.Name" id="Name" value="Name"/>
```

If I use the old style, it is able to save the checked value.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { id = "Name" })
```

Can someone tell what is wrong in "input type=checkbox" statement?

Comment: With razor problems like this, just view the generated HTML (from Razor version) and see what differences you may have.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in "value". For checkbox it is "true" or "false". Setting it to "true" solved the issue.

`<input type="checkbox" checked="@Model.Name" id="Name" value="Name"/>` should be `<input type="checkbox" checked="@Model.Name" id="Name" value="true"/>`